# Async await and then on the same function

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, controller, sequelize.js

Is there a better way to do this with Sequelize?
The point is, how can I know if the update worked without use .then and .catch, because I'm already using inside and async function, and I need to validate if the update really worked.

```
async update(req, res) {
        const owner = await Owner.findByPk(req.params.ownerId);

        if (owner) {
            const { name, email, password, type } = req.body;
        
            owner.update({ name, email, password, type })
                .then(result => {
                    return res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Owner updated' });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', message: err });
                });
        }

        return res.status(404).json({ status: 'not found', message: 'Owner not found' });
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async`/`await` syntax instead

```js
try {
  await owner.update({ name, email, password, type });
  return res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Owner updated' });
} catch (err) {
  return res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', message: err });
}
```